# Find third latest date in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a situation where I need to get the third latest date, i.e

INPUT :

```
['14-04-2001', '29-12-2061', '21-10-2019',
 '07-01-1973', '19-07-2014','11-03-1992','21-10-2019']
```

Also , INPUT

```
6
14-04-2001
29-12-2061
21-10-2019
07-01-1973
19-07-2014
11-03-1992
```

OUTPUT : 19-07-2014

```
import datetime
datelist = ['14-04-2001', '29-12-2061', '21-10-2019', '07-01-1973', '19-07-2014','11-03-1992','21-10-2019' ]
for d in datelist:
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%d-%m-%Y')
    print x
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please don't call your list `list`, You'll find a lot of trouble that way. As for the problem: 1) build a new list with the datetime objects, 2) sort that list 3) get the third last element from that list.

Comment: @dhke edited , i tried using sorted , but not sure how to implement

Comment: `sorted(list, key=lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%d-%m-%Y'), reverse=True)`. Note that sorted returns a generator, so you can't just `[2]` on it.

Comment: i also need to get rid of the duplicate date '21-10-2019'

Comment: do you want third latest day w.r.t. today ?

Comment: @Bijoy Not today, sort in increasing to decresing and get the 3rd one, but get rid of duplicate

Comment: @dhke no - `sorted` returns a `list` - so indexing into it is fine...

Comment: @JonClements I tried doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the list and take the 3rd element from it.

```
my_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%d-%m-%Y') for d in list]
# [datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2061, 12, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1992, 3, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 0, 0)]
my_list.sort(reverse=True)
my_list[2]
# datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 0, 0)
```

Also, as per Kerorin's suggestion, if you don't need to sort in-place and just need the 3rd element always, you can simply do

```
sorted(my_list, reverse=True)[2]
```

**Update**

To remove the duplicates, taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016257/2689986), you can do the following -

```
import datetime

datelist = ['14-04-2001', '29-12-2061', '21-10-2019', '07-01-1973', '19-07-2014', '11-03-1992', '21-10-2019']
seen = set()
my_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%d-%m-%Y')
           for d in datelist
           if d not in seen and not seen.add(d)]
my_list.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: Additional: `sorted(my_list, reverse=True)[2]` is also accepted.

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Does this gets rid of duplicate 21-10-2019'

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Can you make it more of a code rather like input on console, also getting rid of duplicate

Comment: @Kittystone Updated the answer for deduping, had already edit it for non-console code style.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Not able to execute properly, can you please create a proper def ? , also i update the input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152322/discussion-between-kittystone-and-ashish-nitin-patil).

Comment: To get rid of duplicating, juse use `sorted(set([datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%m-%Y') for d in datelist]), reverse=True)[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to do this.

```
import heapq
from datetime import datetime


datelist = [
    '14-04-2001',
    '29-12-2061', 
    '21-10-2019',
    '07-01-1973', 
    '19-07-2014', 
    '11-03-1992', 
    '21-10-2019'
]

heapq.nlargest(3, {datetime.strptime(d, "%d-%m-%Y") for d in datelist})[-1]
```

This return `datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 0, 0)`